# Containers are deleted by finishing the Gitlab process

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, podman

I have created a customer Podman runner for GitLab (free version) which is running on redhat8. I have node programm with 2 modules (client and server) and I am trying to get the client part running, which means create the image and run the container in a pod (lm-dev)
The creating of images and containres ends with success in GitLab CI/CD.

The GitLab logs shows that the build of image is done and podman run and other commands are all running successful but after finishing the process there is no containr either a pod which should have been created too!
I can not understand why the containers are somehow gone or mybe are not created at all although GitLab shows that the process is successfull.
My expectation was to see the lm-client-dev container in the lm-dev pod.

Before finishing the pipeline the only containres that are created are the followings which are deleted by the finishing the job:

```
root@mail ~]# podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                                                              
COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS       NAMES
20becf621320  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64- 
8925d9a0  gitlab-runner-bui...  2 minutes ago   Exited (0) 2 minutes ago               runner- 
xvb7r9ea-project-23-concurrent-0-7c8467ce3ac6d0a3-predefined-0
9d179591b645  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64- 
8925d9a0  gitlab-runner-bui...  2 minutes ago   Exited (0) 2 minutes ago               runner- 
xvb7r9ea-project-23-concurrent-0-7c8467ce3ac6d0a3-predefined-1
bb265fceb3e8  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64- 
8925d9a0  gitlab-runner-bui...  2 minutes ago   Exited (0) 2 minutes ago               runner- 
xvb7r9ea-project-23-concurrent-0-7c8467ce3ac6d0a3-predefined-2
9681b6701bf2  quay.io/podman/stable:latest                                                       
sh -c if [ -x /us...  2 minutes ago   Exited (0) 10 seconds ago              runner-xvb7r9ea- 
project-23-concurrent-0-7c8467ce3ac6d0a3-build-3
9c9f447ae78c  registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64- 
8925d9a0  
gitlab-runner-bui...  10 seconds ago  Up 9 seconds ago
```

My runner is created on the server as follow:

```
gitlab-runner register --non-interactive 
--name "sdx-runner" --url "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/" 
--registration-token "jghfcZXXqZB-xJ-hfgL" --executor 
docker --docker-privileged=true --env "DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/podman/podman.sock" 
--docker-image alpine:latest --docker-volumes 
"/run/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/podman/podman.sock" --tag-list "sdx-runner-pod"
```

My yml (build and tests are ommited here):

```
stages:
- deploy

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

cache:
  paths:
    - client/node_modules/
    - server/node_modules/

 deploy:
   image: "podman"
   stage: deploy
   script:
    - cd client
    - podman build -t lm-client-dev .
    #- podman pod create --name lm-dev --publish 8443:80
    #- podman pod start lm-dev
    #- podman run -p 4250:80 -d lm-client-dev --pod=lm-dev
    - podman run -dt --pod new:lm-dev -p 4250:3000 lm-client-dev top
  tags:
    - sdx-runner-pod
```

My gitlab-runner:

```
[root@mail ~]# gitlab-runner -v
Version:      14.1.0
Git revision: 8925d9a0
Git branch:   14-1-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-07-20T11:43:26+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

My Dockerfile for client which I try to build and run so I can connect to it from my local machine:

```
FROM docker.io/library/node:16.6.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@7.20.6
COPY  . ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: can it be that the free version only  supports CI??

Answer (score 0):

I changed my runner from Docker in shell and could achieve what I needed.